# How to explicit pass 'undefined' to a function, trying to fall back to default value?

Tags: flutter, dart

Say I have a function named `printInt`.

```dart
void printInt({int v = 0}) {
  print(v);
}
```

I read integer `v` from some JSON map object.

```dart
void main(){
  ...
  int v = someJSONMap['v']; // i don't know whether v is null

  // i want to do something like this:
  //    (which not valid in dart)
  //    printInt(v: v == null ? undefined : v);
}
```

I can not change `printInt` (not belongs to me), and I don't want to write codes like this cause the real situation is much more complex.

```
// i don't want to write like this:
if(v == null){
  print();
}else{
  print(v);
}
```

Is there any alternative solution for the above?

Comment: `print(v ?? '')`;

Comment: @Eugene  no, I can not modify `printInt`

Comment: then `printInt(v ?? 0)`

Comment: Can you please add your expected and actual result?

Comment: There is no way to directly use the default value for a function's optional parameter without invoking the function and omitting the argument.  You unfortunately will need to explicitly pass that default value in the caller, as in Eugene's last suggestion.  Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33918